# Python некорректно записывает в csv файл

Tags: python, csv

Есть условный список:

```
list = [
    [1,2,3],
    [4,5,6],
    [7,8,9]
]
```

Мне нужно его записать в csv файл так, чтобы каждая цифра была в отдельной ячейке

[image: <code>введите сюда описание изображения</code>]

На другой машине код ниже работает отлично:

```
with open('r.csv', 'a', newline='') as csvfile:
    writer = csv.writer(csvfile)
    for i in list:
        writer.writerow(i)
```

На моей – результат, почему-то, как на скрине ниже:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Собственно, вопрос: почему так происходит и как это можно исправить?

Comment: в CSV файле нет понятия ячейка. Скорее всего вы открыли файл в Excel и Excel ожидает в качестве разделителя другой символ - например `;`

Comment: @MaxU, в самом CSV - да. и Вы совершенно правы, что я открывал файл в Excel'e. Собственно, и проблема заключалась, как я и описал, в том, что на другой машине все отображалось как нужно.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import csv

myList = [
    [1,2,3],
    [4,5,6],
    [7,8,9]
]

with open('r.csv', 'a', newline='') as csvfile:
    writer = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=';')   # + delimiter=';'
    for i in myList:
        writer.writerow(i)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]